# Coverting String to LocalTime with/without nanoOfSeconds

Tags: java, java-8, formatter, java-time, localtime

I need to convert a string to LocalTime (java-8 not joda) that may or maynot have nanoOfSeconds in the string. The String format is in the form of 
    `07:06:05` or `07:06:05.123456` 
The string may or may not have a decimal place in the seconds and when it does there could be any number of characters to represent the Nano Seconds part.

Using a DateTimeForamtter such as

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
```

or

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

I can use an IF statement to distinguish between the two formats such as:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf;
if (time1.contains(".") {
   dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss.SSSSSS);
} else {
   dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss);
}
```

This works fine and I'm OK with this but I need to be able to also use a varying number of positions after the decimal point.

A sample data set might be:

```
[11:07:59.68750, 11:08:00.781250, 11:08:00.773437500, 11:08:01]
```

Is there a way to allow the formatter to parse any number of digits after the decimal without it throwing a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` when the number of decimal places is unknown?

I'm hoping I missing something really simple.

Comment: to answer the first question, it seems that you could simply test the length of the string `if (stringValue.length() > 7) { //use second formatter } else if (stringValue.length() == 7) { //use first formatter }` I'm not sure I understand the second question, could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the second either - I'm hoping it's irrelevant given my answer to the first :)

Comment: Seems ugly to have to check for a specific number of places and decide on a format based on that. Seems logical to have a formatter that was a little less strict on number of characters (but then again we are dealing with strings)

Comment: Well for not I will settle for a combination of if statements and manually truncating the string to a fixed number of positions `if(strValue.length()> 12) { strValue = strValue.substring(0,12);}. This is ugly and hope someone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no need to do anything special to parse this format. `LocalTime.parse(String)` already handles optional nanoseconds:

```
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("10:15:30"));
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("10:15:30."));
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("10:15:30.1"));
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("10:15:30.12"));
System.out.println(LocalTime.parse("10:15:30.123456789"));
```

All the above parse fine, see also the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME).

Comment: what if the string don't have `:`?

Comment: how about "9:00"?

Answer (score 8):

You could use "optional sections" of the format pattern for this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss[.SSSSSS]");
```

Comment: yea but will that let me me have a varied amount of decimal places?

Comment: @jbolt: It would help if you would clarify your question to explain what you mean.

Comment: question 2 was I need to parse an unknown number of places after the decimal. It could be 0 or more places (the decimal could even not be included) hence the two different time signatures

Comment: @jbolt: That's still not really clear. Giving examples of what you're asking for would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @jbolt: Not a lot - are you saying if there *are* more than 3 decimal places, you still only want to parse the first three? Again, *examples* would help - sample input and expected output.