# How to insert Hours and Minutes through ComboBox in Java

Tags: java

I want to take hours and minutes as input from user through a Combo box. I tried but i couldn't convert String into hours and minutes

Comment: *"I tried..."* what?  Help us out so we don't go over the same ground and waste each other time

Comment: [`LocalTime.of(hour, minute)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int))

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Coverting String to LocalTime with/without nanoOfSeconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788369/coverting-string-to-localtime-with-without-nanoofseconds); [How to convert a given time (String) to a LocalTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595169/how-to-convert-a-given-time-string-to-a-localtime)

Answer (score 1):

Just parse it using the Localtime static methods (See the jdk documentation about Time api).
[localTime.of(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int))

Comment: Seriously? [Why?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int))

Comment: Agreed with @MadProgrammer - no point in teaching inexperienced users to use the old and largely deprecated/useless `Date` class. Instead point them in the direction of the `java.time` package.